# Android - Drawer navigation adapter

Tags: android-listview, android-adapter, android-navigation

I am implementing a navigation Drawer as per: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

The tutorial only shows a single TextView with ID **android:id="@android:id/text1"** and this is populated for the ListView using:

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item,
            mDrawerItems));
```

Now, I want to include an ImageView inside each ListView item. This will represent the Icon for each item.

**Question:** Inside my xml for the list items (where the TextView text1 is located), I have included an ImageView.

1. What do I need to name the ID for the ImageView?
2. And then, do I simply add the drawable-array reference to the setAdapter like this?

   ```
   mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
           this,
           R.layout.drawer_list_item,
           mDrawerItems,
           mDrawerIcons));
   ```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that creating an `ArrayAdapter` in the format above does not allow you to input more than one set of data to the `Adapter`. For instance, I can only use my list of Drawer Navigation names contained in the `Array<String>`: mDrawerItems. To pass Icons and other data to the adapter, I have two option:

1. `Simple Adapter` used with a `Map`, or
2. Custom Adapter.

Examples of both can be found here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html, and here:

http://www.shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/